# ILNumerics - Visual Studio integration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ilnumerics

I have been trying to integrate ILNumerics with VS, following the instructions on the ILNumerics website.

I am using VS-2013-Express-Desktop under Windows 8.1 with ILNumerics Trial Edition.
I am interested in acquiring the Standard Edition, after the trial period expires; nevertheless, I would like to be able to use the software at its full potential.

I can add ILNumerics references from VS Express Desktops and the code seems working, I can also import data, as prescribed; but I am unable to install the Visual Studio Extension.

From the error code I get it would seem that ILNumerics extension is supported only for Pro,Ultimate, and Premimum Edition of VS, on the 'Express' side only the Windows edition seems to be supported. Is it so?

Is there anyway to install the mentioned extensions for VS  Express Desktop edition?

What are the main advantages that I miss? On the documentation it would seem there are some templates and the array visualiser; anything else?

Thanks in advance,

GL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Editions of Visual Studio do not allow any third party extensions. Therefore, you need one of the paid editions in order for the extension to show up. However, most of ILNumerics will still be available and work as expected. But you would miss the Array Visualizer and the item templates. Also, in certain situations, ILPanel may not show up in the toolbox in the forms designer. In that case, you can add it manually and work with it as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much, as usual. I was afraid I would have needed a paid edition, but it does not seem a serious limitation. Thanks again and congrats for ILNumerics